# Available dataset containing private/confidential documents

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, classification, text

I'm looking to build a classifier that can label documents as `private` or `public` based on their content and need to find a suitable dataset that contains private/confidential/secret/sensitive documents.

It's fairly easy to understand that they are hard to find since they contain 'private/confidential/secret/sensitive' information. However, most datasets I have discovered have had the important parts redacted or cleansed.

Anyone have any suggestions for a dataset or even a place to look for such a dataset?

Comment: something like this? https://www.neboagency.com/blog/security-alert-simple-google-queries-uncover-sensitive-government-documents/

Comment: *private or public based on their content* -> What's private depends on context (E.g. [1](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2006/05/the_value_of_pr.html), [2](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=998565)), so if you are not defining any context it's practically impossible what *private/etc* is (other than those exact words at the top of the text). Please [edit] your question to give context.